# Longitudinal Study into attention bias and insomnia - What test to use?

Tags: correlation, panel-data

I am doing a study into attentional bias (as measured by the Stroop test) and insomnia (as measured by the Insomnia Severity Index - ISI).

I will be comparing the mean reaction times of the Stroop test to the mean ISI scores at 4 different time points (Baseline, 3 month follow up, 6 month follow up and 9 month follow up).

If I was looking at the relationship between the 2 means at one time point, I would do a Pearson r, but i know I cannot use this longitudinally as it violates Pearson r assumptions.

How do I look at the relationship between the 2 scores over time?

Any help GREATLY appreciated!